# What happens to an RTG if the demand exceeds supply?

Tags: voyager, rtg

[NASA](http://voyager.jpl.nasa.gov/spacecraft/spacecraftlife.html) writes to say

> As the electrical power becomes less and less, power loads on the spacecraft must be turned off in order to avoid having demand exceed supply.

A lead battery would 'die' **if demand were to exceed supply** for any sustained duration ; What happens to an RTG in the same situation?

Answer (score 14):

As you demand more current, the voltage goes down.  You eventually brown-out the system.  The RTG doesn't care.  If you then reduce the load, the voltage goes back up.

You cannot drain an RTG like a battery.  Its power output depends only on its radioactivity (which goes down over time), the efficiency of the thermocouples (which also goes down a little over time), and the temperature of the sink.

Comment: Also, Thermocouples generally don't seem to mind even if they are short circuited.. There might be ones where there are thin traces or fuse that could burn out in the case of a short circuit but the thermocouples themselfes seem to be tolerant.